Use gitlab to deploy files to servers
we have a private jar file that we consistently deploy to different servers (DEV, TEST, PROD). For CI/CD we are using gitlab.
How can I store that file, so that I can define in my gitlab ci/cd to copy that file to specific locations on the server.
Kind Regards
